# Total contracts by month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the total contracts by month. Data is stored in columns  (Start Date) and (End Date) multiple lines of data for each month.

```
SELECT e.CustomerID, e.AgentID,
COUNT(*) engagementnumber
FROM Engagements e
GROUP BY EndDate
```

The first time I ran the code with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) engagementnumber,
FROM Engagements,
GROUP BY EndDate
```

I got a count but it wasn't grouped by month.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Total Contracts by Month for Customers and Agents: Start Date: 2020-09-01 End Date: 2020-09-05, Engagement Number 1, CustomerId:, Agent Id

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot the dates and use aggregation:

```
select year(dte), month(dte),
       sum(inc) as change_in_month,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by min(dte) as active_in_month
from ((select startdate as dte, 1 as inc from Engagements) union all
      (select enddate, -1 as int from Engagements)
     ) t
group by year(dte), month(dte)
order by year(dte), month(dte);
```

Comment: can you explain what dte and inc represents?

Comment: @DakotaChittim . . . They represent each `date` and inc represents whether the account starts being counted or ends being counted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
SELECT MONTH(enddate), COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(enddate)) engagementnumber FROM engagements
```